# Getting input post not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I´m trying to update a specific column in database using codeigniter, the problem is that for some reason I´m not able to get the "ID" I´m going to update, it says that is empty but I don´t find the problem. Any hero without a cape out there?
This is my controller:

```
function search2()
{
  if ($_POST) {
      $Interno=$_POST['Interno'];
  }else{
    $Interno = '';
  }
  $this->db->select('empleados.Interno, empleados.Curp, empleados.Nombre, empleados.A_Paterno, empleados.A_Materno, cuentas.Clabe, cuentas.Banco, cuentas.Observaciones, cuentas.Status');
$this->db->from('empleados');
$this->db->join('cuentas',"cuentas.Interno = empleados.Interno AND cuentas.Status !='I'", 'Left');
$this->db->where('empleados.Interno', $Interno);
$q = $this->db->get();
$data = array();
$data['records'] = $q->result_array();
$this ->load -> view('main/indice', $data); 


}

function update_Status() 
{
$Interno = $this->input->post('Interno');

$Status = $this->input->post('Inactivo');

$data['status'] = ! empty($Status) ? $Status : 'I';
if ( ! empty($Interno))
{
    $updated = $this->consultas_M->update_Status($Interno, $data);
    if($updated)
    {
       echo " update successful...";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "update not successful...";
    }  
}
else
{
    echo "Interno  not found ...";
}    
}
```

This is my model:

```
function update_Status($Interno,$data)
{
   $this->db->where('Interno', $Interno);
   return $this->db->update('cuentas', $data);
   if ( $this->db->affected_rows() > 0 )
   {
     return TRUE;
   }
   else 
   {
     return FALSE;
   }
   }
```

This is the view:

```
<form  action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Datos/validaclabe" method="post" class="form-inline form-responsive">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <br>
                    <?php
    foreach ($records as $row) {
            echo"<br></br>";
            echo "<label class='control-label'>Interno</label>";
            echo "<input type='number' id='Interno'  name ='Interno' class='form-control Input col-sm-3' value='".$row['Interno']."'>";
            echo "<label class='control-label'>CURP</label>";
            echo "<input type='text' id='curp' name ='curp' class='form-control Input col-sm-3' placeholder='Curp' value='".$row['Curp']."'>";
            echo "<label class='control-label'>nombre</label>";
            echo "<input type='text' id='nombre' name ='nombre' class='form-control Input col-sm-3' placeholder='Nombre' value='".$row['Nombre']."'>";
            echo "<label class='control-label'>Apellido Paterno</label>";
            echo "<input type='text' id='A_Paterno' name ='A_Paterno' class='form-control Input col-sm-2' placeholder='Apellido Paterno' value='".$row['A_Paterno']."'>";
            echo "<label class='control-label'>Apellido Materno</label>";
            echo "<input type='text' id='A_Materno' name ='A_Materno' class='form-control Input col-sm-1' placeholder='Apellido Materno' value='".$row['A_Materno']."'>"; 

               echo "<label class='control-label'>Clabe</label>";
            echo "<input type='text' id='Clabe' name ='Clabe' class='form-control Input col-sm-3' placeholder='' value='".$row['Clabe']."'>";
            echo "<label class='control-label'>Banco</label>";
            echo "<input type='text' id='Banco' name ='Banco' class='form-control Input col-sm-2' placeholder='' value='".$row['Banco']."'>";
            echo "<label class='control-label'>Observaciones</label>";
            echo "<input type='text' id='Observaciones' name ='Observaciones' class='form-control Input col-sm-1' placeholder='' value='".$row['Observaciones']."'>"; 

            echo "<input type='hidden' id='Status' name ='Status' class='form-control Input col-sm-1' value='".$row['Status']."'>";
    }
  ?>
  <input type="hidden" id="Inactivo" name="Inactivo" value="I" placeholder="I">
          </div>

          <div class="" align="rigth">
   <button type="submit" id="actualizar" name="actualizar" class="btn btn-primary active" onclick ="return validacion()">Nueva Cuenta</button>
   <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Datos/update_Status" id="Desactivar" name="Desactivar" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return val2()">Desactivar Cuenta</a><span id="msg"></span>
    </div>
```

When I try to do the update, it sends me to the second else condition where it says "Interno not found" (Interno is the ID) I don´t know why it isn´t found.
Again thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: what is the use of this in anchor `onclick="return val2()"`

Comment: It´s a javascript function that prevents user from clicking "update account" if he doesn´t have any account registered.                                       
           function val2(){
           valor = document.getElementById("Clabe").value;
        if( valor.length > 0) {
         return true;
       }else{
          document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "No tiene una 
        cuenta registrada, dé en agregar primero";
        return false;
         }

           }

Comment: pls explain how you deactivating your records, on anchor click or something else

Comment: I don´t get yout comment.

Comment: i am saying if want to update any record it should be a single record at a time to update , your anchor href should have a particular id of the record to be updated and on click anchor that particular id will be sent to your controller

Comment: and moreover your anchor should be within loop to get the particular id of the record to be updated

Comment: you have a form with `action` and a `loop` within your form and also have anchor with `href` attr and `onclick` events  which one goes where ,very confusing

Comment: Yea, I seem to understand I changed the href for a submit botton and changed the action form to update_Status, just as a test, and it worked this time, I know I have many actions and loops and stuff but I need to do many decisions in that form. I´m doing tests to solve the problem